# Overwrite Codeigniter Pagination total_rows

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have CI pagination set up and working as expected so far. As suggested in the CI docs, a I am using a pagination config file. I chose to do this to keep the controller tidy. The issue I am experiencing is that I do not know how to access and overwrite the total_rows variable.

For example, I set the variable to 200 in the config file. In my app, the number of records will be higher. I want to dynamically modify the variable locally in the controller.

I can see the object contents (below) using "print_r($this->pagination);"

```
CI_Pagination Object
(
    [base_url:protected] => http://moxietek.com/mx03/index.php/user/index/
    [prefix:protected] => 
    [suffix:protected] => 
    [total_rows:protected] => 200
    [num_links:protected] => 3
    [per_page] => 20
    [cur_page] => 0
    [use_page_numbers:protected] => 
    [first_link:protected] => First
    [next_link:protected] => Next
    [prev_link:protected] => Previous
    [last_link:protected] => Last
...)
```

Of the Q&A on pagination, each use the config setup in the controller. I can do this and everything will work, but I ultimately want to reuse the pagination configuration for other controllers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the config array item key will be overridden by any element you pass to initialize:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['total_rows'] = 50;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

So while `total_rows` overrides the one `/config/pagination.php` the other variables set aren't overridden.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your response. I used your suggestion and it worked. Oddly though the initialization wiped out the 'attributes' setting so my CSS was wacked out. I was able to correct that by moving '$config['attributes'] = array("class" => "page-link rounded-0 mw25px");' to the controller - simple enough. Appreciate your help. Cheers.